# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: routeParamsProvider <- routeParams using LazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I'm using LazyLoad to make a on-demand load of the angular controllers, and trying to build all the paths at the moment, but always getting the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: routeParamsProvider <- routeParams
```

Below it's the routeProvider snippet

```
 $routeProvider
            .when("/", {templateUrl: "principal/index"})
            .when('/:controller/:action', {
                templateUrl: function(routeParams){
                    return routeParams.controller+"/"+ routeParams.action;
                },
                resolve: function(routeParams){
                    lazyLoad('assets/controller/'+routeParams.controlador+'/'+routeParams.controller+'Controller.js');
                    return lazyload; 
                },
                controller: function(routeParams){ 
                    return routeParams.action;
                }
            })
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authHttpResponseInterceptor');
            $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
      }]);
```

I can't even get a console.log about the path that the lazyLoad function it's receiving.

Any suggestion about what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"routeParams" does not work inside resolve. Use "$route.current.params" instead.

Try this:

```js
$routeProvider
            .when("/", {templateUrl: "principal/index"})
            .when('/:controller/:action', {
                templateUrl: function($route){
                    return $route.current.params.controller+"/"+ $route.current.params.action;
                },
                resolve: function($route){
                    lazyLoad('assets/controller/'+$route.current.params.controlador+'/'+$route.current.params.controller+'Controller.js');
                    return lazyload; 
                },
                controller: function($route){ 
                    return $route.current.params.action;
                }
            })
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authHttpResponseInterceptor');
            $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
      }]);
```

Cheers